# Access file with file : // url

Tags: ios, path

I have created an application which  can upload locally saved files in to amazon server

i this app i have used `NSURLSessionUploadTask` to upload files ,

but in here

```
@try {
      task = [[self backgroundURLSession] uploadTaskWithRequest:request2 fromFile:url];
      [task resume];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"exception %@",exception);
    }
```

i recieve  ,  **not valid URL file://url exception** , then i checked my file url and it is

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7494DF09-866A-4088-AC73-710A21A6569A/Documents/xxxx/1417516256_event_138_footage_1209_cam_001.mp4

how can i change my URL in to **file://** type, and what is the meaning of file:// where does it located

Comment: how you have created url object can u share code of that?

Comment: @johnykumar first i save my file in this location . then i save this file in local db , then i retrieve it , which part u want to review

Comment: @johnykumar i save this ile path in local DB , and i use SQL lite to take it from saved table,

Comment: FYI    footage.videoOutPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]; this returns path , and also if check file availability from here , it returns not available ,

Comment: if it is returning not available then may be problem is in saving file in Db.

Comment: but i checked this once i save the , then it says its there , but if i navigate to another view controller , then it says it doesn't  , this i phonegap + native iOS app